# Cox regression slope - understanding the sign of the slope

Tags: regression, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am using the [`coxme`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/coxme.pdf) package in R to perform mixed effect cox regression analysis, and **would greatly appreciate some advice on how to interpret the regression slopes.** The data is a response variable (*lifespan*), converted to a survival object (age at death, and information on censoring). There are two *sexes* (M: male, and F: female) and two *groups* (G1 and G2), and sampling was performed in two separate *years*, and there is a continuous explanatory variable (*NE*). I use sex, group and NE as fixed effects, and year as a random effect, because the aim is to quantify the differences in response to NE ($\beta$), for the within-sex and with-group comparisons:

- $\beta_{M,G1} - \beta_{F,G1}$
- $\beta_{M,G2} - \beta_{F,G2}$
- $\beta_{M,G1} - \beta_{M,G2}$
- $\beta_{F,G1} - \beta_{F,G2}$

**So here is some dummy data and the model (in R):**

```
n = 2000
set.seed(1239)
dumDF = data.frame(
    "Sex" = sample(c("M","F"), size = n, replace = T), 
    "Group" = sample(c("G1","G2"), replace = T),
    "Year" = sample(c("1994","1995"), replace = T), 
    "NE" = rnorm(n,0,5), 
    "Status" = sample(c(1,2,2,2), replace = T), 
    "Life" = rnorm(n, 50, 5))

dumDF$Life = ifelse(dumDF$Sex=="M", dumDF$Life -10 + dumDF$NE, dumDF$Life+dumDF$NE)

dumDF$SurvObj = with(dumDF, Surv(Life, Status == 2))
coxdum <- coxme(SurvObj ~ Sex*Group*NE + (1|Year), data = dumDF)
coxdum

> coxdum
Cox mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: dumDF
  events, n = 1000, 2000
  Iterations= 1 7 
                    NULL Integrated   Fitted
Log-likelihood -6597.047   -6104.89 -6104.89

                   Chisq df p    AIC    BIC
Integrated loglik 984.32  8 0 968.32 929.05
 Penalized loglik 984.32  7 0 970.32 935.96

Model:  SurvObj ~ Sex * Group * NE + (1 | Year) 
Fixed coefficients
                        coef exp(coef)   se(coef)      z      p
SexM             1.971525293 7.1816222 0.10196386  19.34 0.0000
GroupG2         -0.035924373 0.9647132 0.08891258  -0.40 0.6900
NE              -0.176770390 0.8379722 0.01356340 -13.03 0.0000
SexM:GroupG2     0.004847530 1.0048593 0.12708703   0.04 0.9700
SexM:NE         -0.053164686 0.9482238 0.01909755  -2.78 0.0054
GroupG2:NE      -0.001227879 0.9987729 0.01866811  -0.07 0.9500
SexM:GroupG2:NE  0.043730917 1.0447012 0.02699633   1.62 0.1100

Random effects
 Group Variable  Std Dev Variance
 Year  Intercept 2e-02   4e-04
```

**I then reconstruct the slopes from the estimated coefficients:**

```
coxSlopeFunc = function(model, nfixed = 1){
    if(nfixed ==1){
    # Slope for Females + Group 1
    FG1 = model$coefficients[3]
    # Slope for Males + Group 1
    MG1 = model$coefficients[3] + model$coefficients[5]

    # Slope for Females + Group 2
    FG2 = model$coefficients[3] + model$coefficients[6]
    # Slope for Males + Group 2
    MG2 = model$coefficients[3] + model$coefficients[5] + model$coefficients[6] + model$coefficients[7]

    matrix(c(FG1,MG1,MG2,FG2), ncol = 1)
    }
}
coxSlopeFunc(coxdum)

> coxSlopeFunc(coxdum)
             [,1]
[1,] -0.176770390
[2,] -0.229935076
[3,] -0.187432037
[4,] -0.177998268
```

As you can see, the slopes are all negative ([1,] through [4,]). It is understanding the meaning of these slopes that I am stuck on.

**Would it be correct to say that a negative slope means there is a decreasing hazard (and therefore reduced mortality) with increasing NE?** In other words, if the slope is negative, the explanatory variable reduces the rate of mortality?

Furthermore, if the value of NE increases by a unit of 1, is the hazard ($H$) expected to change by $H \times (1 + \beta)$?

---

Update:

As [I read this](https://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf) I interpret the response to be the log of the individual hazard function, $log \space h_i(t)$, as given on page 3. Thus, a negative slope would indicate that the hazard (mortality) reduces with increasing NE.